# File manager with tags and video preview

Tags: windows, file-management, tags

Is there a tagged file manager with video previews that you get in the normal windows explorer?

I tried these tagged file managers and none of them have a video preview for videos, often showing blank or default icons.

- Elyse
- Tabbles
- Xyplorer
- Tagged Frog

Comment: In 2024, for Windows 10 and up, Brows will begin playing video files in the preview pane (ALT+P) when they're selected. https://brows.app